# Why exactly pipe is simple than TCP connection between SSL proxy and HTTP proxy communicating?

Tags: http, ssl, tcp, proxy, pipe

I began to study protocol stuffs recently. 
I acknowledged that in the old method, incoming data will be first delivered to SSL proxy, where to be decrypted and then be sent to HTTP proxy through another TCP connection. For every packet passes through this connection, we need to do a connection table to look up to determine the other endpoint of the connection.

But the pipe setup and teardown require one function call each and no packet sent. Sending data through the pipe will not require a connection table lookup, as the data structures are already tied together with pointers.

I tried to search the answer of my own question, but can’t find good method to understand it. I guess there may be something related to structure of TCP or PIPE. Could any tell me that why exactly pipe is simple than TCP connection between SSL proxy and HTTP proxy? Or please suggest me what book to read or how can I understand it?

Two Pics related to this question:
http://www.tripntale.com/pic/19254/857880/pipe-jpg#pid-857880
http://www.tripntale.com/pic/19254/857880/pipe-jpg#pid-857882

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. It sounds like you might be talking about an implementation of a proxy. Also "pipe is simple than TCP connection" doesn't make any sense. What kind of pipe? What does "simple" mean to you in the context of comparing this pipe to a TCP connection?

Comment: Please forgive my poor English. There is a image could interpret what i said, but i can't upload it because of the reputation.

Comment: Can you edit your question with a link to the image?

Comment: Yeah, here are two pics，
http://www.tripntale.com/pic/19254/857880/pipe-jpg#pid-857882
http://www.tripntale.com/pic/19254/857880/pipe-jpg#pid-857880

Comment: That link just displays 'Sorry. the Trip you're trying to visit is not available anymore.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you want to know is how these two diagrams compare?

I'm sorry to say that these diagrams don't make much sense to me either, hopefully they do make sense if there's the text to go with them when they were published.

The diagrams relate to software engineering approaches to a problem, but the objects in the diagrams aren't defined functionally, appear to me to be used in different ways and it isn't clear what the problem is that these are approaches to.

HTTP proxies can be used as:

1. Forward proxies (client sends it's HTTP requests to proxy, proxy fetches and returns them to client)
   Or
2. Reverse proxies (proxy sits in front of server(s) for service engineering reasons)

The term "SSL Proxy" could refer to either application and would have differing implications to how it was designed.

See here for more explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL_Proxy

---

Do you just want to understand these diagrams? Or are you trying to solve a problem and think that these diagrams can help you? If so, what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I was trying to understand it ^^.

Comment: First time I asked the question, and I think I asked a vague question. Thanks for answering me. The only way to solve this question perfectly is to read more and understand more. I will study this part and figure out what exactly the diagrams were trying to say. And i will print my understanding soon, to make sure that your time wasn't in vain. Thanks again, and please forgive my poor English again~

Answer (score 0):

> For every packet passes through this connection, we need to do a
>   connection table

Why? I've written several proxies without a connection table.